# How to view the code of a flash video player (.flv file)?

Tags: flash, flv, flvplayer

Total Flash noob here.

We have an embedded flash object that plays an mp3, then shows a button, you click it to continue to another page. We recently changed our domain, so this now logs the user out.

My problem is I can't find the actual code for these flv files. When I open them in Flash Pro it doesn't show the code, it only shows a GUI-type thing (it reminds me of drag and drop for VB or something). Meanwhile I decoded the swf object that is embedded in the page, and it shows the ACTUAL code. Why can I not see this code when I open the flv file in Flash Pro?

If it matters, it says v 2.4260 in the player.

Answer (score 1):

The FLV and F4V file formats are data formats for media (video and audio), *not* ActionScript compiled files.  This is why you can't simply 'open' a .flv file in Flash.  Reference: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/f4v.html

FLV files are used when you need to download/stream media to a Flash Object, commonly known as a .swf file. It is important to note that the Flash file (.fla) that is compiled down to a .swf file which can load one or more .flv files, can overlay animation, text, buttons, etc. on top of the FLVPlayback Component which is usually what is used to stream/download the .flv file for playback in a .swf file.